# How to group by month using X-Path expression/XSLT in SPDesigner

Tags: sharepoint, xslt, xpath, sharepoint-designer

I have a 3 way grouping done on a SharePoint list. There's a month column which is the 3rd level of grouping in that. Even though I checked "Ascending" for the month column in designer, it still doesn't sort the month column properly. Note: Month is a calculated column in SharePoint calculated based on the created date and is "MMM". I tried to edit the Sort Expression for month but I have no knowledge of XPath for that. Please help me in doing this.

Comment: Could you show us the portion of the XSLT where the sort expression is?  By "MMM", do you mean something like Jan, Feb, Mar?  If so, is there another column that has the month as a number?

Comment: Umm, I don't know where that code is. I just sorted it using the OOB group & sort feature. Yes, the former not the latter.

Comment: So are the months being sorted alphabetically? (Apr, Aug, Feb, Jan, ...)? Do you have a separate column with the numerical months?  If not, can you add one?

Comment: Yes, the alphabetical order. Strange why I didn't notice that... Hmm, isn't this possible using the current scenario? Don't really want to add another column with numerical months.

Comment: @JLRishe so can this only be done using another column with numerical months as a sort field? Can't this be done using some XSLT or some XPath modification in the Advanced Sort box?

Comment: Well, if you have a `Date` column with its underlying value in the format `yyyy-MM-dd`, and you're allowed to use XPath expressions in the filtering dialog, then you could sort on `substring(Date, 6, 2)`.  I don't think there's a good way to sort on MMM values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a Date column in your list with its underlying value in the format yyyy-MM-dd, and you can use XPath expressions in the filtering dialog, then you could sort on the formula (after substituting in the actual column name for the date):

```
substring(Date, 6, 2)
```

This would sort on the numeric month portion of the date.

One other option to be able to sort on the Month field would be to sort on the value of this formula:

```
string-length(substring-before('JanFebMarAprMayJunJulAugSepOctNovDec', Month)) + 100
```

If the actual values of the `Month` column are different from "Jan", "Feb", etc., please adjust accordingly.

The last option would be to add a Month column with the numerical value of the month, and sort on that.